# Issue with Tie function in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I still a beginner with jQuery and JavaScript, but I wrote this Tic Tac Toe game for a class assignment. The game works, except for this one bug that I can't seem to figure out.

The problem is when all 9 squares are filled, it should return a tie which it does. But if the last square is the winning marker, it will return who the winner is along with the tie.

I have tried adding in `if (totalTurns === 9 && checkForWinner === false)` in the checkForEndOfGame function, but then there is another issue. If all 9 squares are filled with a winner, it will return that winner only. But if all 9 squares are filled with no winner, it will not return the tie.

So if I do it one way, I get the first issue. If I do it the other way, I get the second issue. I'm stumped on why and how this could be fixed. I have attached the link for the jsfiddle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I use images for the 'x' and 'o' markers, but for the purpose of jsfiddle, I just replaced them with a string of 'x' or 'o'.

---

Winning combos are:

```
var winningCombos = [
    // horizontal
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    //vertical
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    //diagonal
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];
```

I check for a winner with:

```
function checkForWinner() {
    winningCombos.forEach(function (win) {
        if (
            board[win[0]] == currentPlayer && 
            board[win[1]] == currentPlayer && 
            board[win[2]] == currentPlayer
        ) {
            alert(playerMarker[currentPlayer] + " is the winner!");
            $("#restartgame").show()
            $("#restartgame").click(function () {
                location.reload();
            });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
};
```

Full code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/p0rL9jmd/

Comment: Your checkForWinner function returns a true/false "is there a winner" value.  You're not capturing it into a variable, which you could use to conditionally call the later functions.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p0rL9jmd/2/ Your checkForWinner was using a forEach, which the return does not immediately return.  I've reworked a lot of the code to fix various issues (Playing before clicking "start game", the double-win bug (Click board positions 0,1,2,3,6,5,8,7 and then 4), etc.